# Questions about distributions on $l$-spaces.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I am reading [the paper](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAC&url=%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%77%77%77%2e%6d%61%74%68%31%2e%74%61%75%2e%61%63%2e%69%6c%2f%7e%62%65%72%6e%73%74%65%69%2f%50%75%62%6c%69%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%5f%6c%69%73%74%2f%70%75%62%6c%69%63%61%74%69%6f%6e%5f%74%65%78%74%73%2f%42%2d%5a%65%6c%2d%52%65%70%73%47%4c%2d%55%73%70%2e%70%64%66&ei=zBSiVaHANM-9uATt34GgAQ&usg=AFQjCNF5OXmVI4Djs4fmAt_5C3ktdZ_F6g&sig2=piTUo-cqKJZ3WVGF0uEupw&bvm=bv.97653015,d.dGo).

I have some about distributions on $l$-spaces. On page 7, Section 1.7. Let $X$ be an $l$-space. Locally constant complex-valued functions on $X$ with compact support are called Schwartz functions on $X$. The space of Schwartz functions on $X$ is denoted by $S(X)$. The space of distributions on $X$ is denoted by $S^*(X)$ (distributions on $X$ are linear functionals on $S(X)$). Let $f \in S(X)$, $T \in S^*(X)$. Then the value of $T$ at $f$ is denoted by $\langle T, f \rangle$ or $\int_X f(x) dT(x)$.

My question is: why we denote the value of $T$ at $f$ by an integral $\int_X f(x) dT(x)$? Thank you very much.

Comment: It comes from the definition of distributions over, say, Euclidean spaces $\mathbb{R}^n$. The name distribution (I think) comes from charge distribution - the intuition is that on Euclidean space, they represent things you can integrate (test) functions against. I.e. the Dirac delta distribution, $\delta(f)=f(0)$, which would, in E&M, represent something like a point charge at the origin.

Comment: In the Euclidean case, the Schwartz functions are defined as smooth functions $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ with compact support. The intuition for the integral sign you asked about also is comes from noting that any (locally Lebesgue) integrable function $f$ defines a distribution, usually also denoted $f$, by the map $g\mapsto\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} fg dV$.

There are some technical conditions to do with analysis that we put on functionals here, in addition to having them in $S^*(X)$. A standard reference is Friedlander and Joshi's "Intro to the Theory of Distributions."

Comment: Another piece of intuition: for certain distributions (those of order 0), the Riesz representation applies, and we can write them as $\langle T,f\rangle=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f\ d\mu$, where $\mu$ is a measure and the integral is a genuine measure-theoretic integral. This is in Friedlander-Joshi somewhere early.